# How-To: Web Application Singleton in a distributed (clustered) web server

Tags: java, cluster-computing, shared-memory, distributed

We developed a J2EE web application (.war). The application runs without problems in Glassfish, Payara and Weblogic (so far). It's supposed it should run in any J2EE compliance Application Server.

Soon the application will be on production and we expect a large number of users. We are considering implementing a cluster in the Application Server in order to properly balance service in several nodes. We have an application-scoped resource that each session must access in exclusive-mode. We achieve the exclusive-access thanks to what it could be called a **MuTex** via calls to `serialized` methods in a application-scoped singleton object. Now, with the new cluster scenario, we need to keep the exclusive-mode access between all the session in all the nodes (each node is executed on his own JVM).

I would like to know which would be the best practices regarding shared objects in distributed environments (nodes of a clustered web application server)?

**How and we achieve the implementation of a singleton object accessible to all the nodes of the cluster?**

Any information or help will be really appreciated.

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: Use something like Redis for locking?